# Wireless Ad-Hoc mesh network implementation for Windows 7

Tags: networking, wireless, adhoc, mesh-network

I have been looking into *Mesh Connectivity Layer* [on Microsoft Research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/mesh/).

The implementation seems to be applicable only for Windows XP.

Is there any freely available `Ad-hoc Mesh` support to help me with Multi-hop ad-hoc mesh networking? I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

For the record the only current way to do anything ad-hoc in Windows is to use the `netsh` command's `wlan * hostednetwork` options, e.g.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid="My AdHoc Network" key=YourPassword keyUsage=persistent mode=allow
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

This is not a mesh of course, but currently the only official solution from Microsoft that comes close.

It only starts manually, so if you want it to start at boot you need to create a task scheduler entry for this.